# ElasticSearch not working on MacOS after update to 7.7.0

Tags: java, macos, elasticsearch

I recently updated ElasticSearch on my Macbook (Catalina 10.15.4) from version 7.6.1 to 7.7.0 with homebrew. After update I can't start service - it is marked as "started" in yellow and ElasticSearch not working. Log is showing only one entry:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/elasticsearch-full/7.7.0/libexec/bin/elasticsearch-env: line 77: 16617 Killed: 9 "$JAVA" "$XSHARE" -cp "$ES_CLASSPATH" org.elasticsearch.tools.java_version_checker.JavaVersionChecker
```

I even updated Java to 11.x but still has this error. More interestingly running `elasticsearch` from command line runs ES successfully and it's working this way but not with brew.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I did to resolve this:

- brew uninstall elasticsearch-full
- brew install elasticsearch-full

Comment: I don't know why I didn't think about trying that before :D That works, thanks!